# How to serialize Array of object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xmlserializer

As shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, we can generate xml of object:

```
MySerializableClass myObject = new MySerializableClass();
// Insert code to set properties and fields of the object.
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new 
XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));
// To write to a file, create a StreamWriter object.
StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("myFileName.xml");
mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myObject);
myWriter.Close();
```

This is working fine, but now I am having Listof MySerializableClass

```
List<Object> lObj = new List<Object>();
Person obj1 = new Person ();
Person obj2 = new Person ();

lobj.add(obj1);
lobj.add(obj2);

CreateXMLOFList(lobj);
```

Can you suggest me to write a function which can generate single XML of List of collection:

example:

```
<Person>
<Name>
Joy
</Name>
</Person>

<Person>
<Name>
 Steive
</Name>
</Person>
```

here `Person` is a class and `Name` is a property.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the .NET `XmlSerializer` will generate an `ArrayOfItem` element when serializing a `List<T>`.

You can circumvent this by creating an own class that derives from `List<T>`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Persons : List<Person>
{
}
```

Or, when it is a property, mark the [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) with a name:

```
[XmlElement("Persons")]
public List<Person> Persons
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni: Need more help?